# 500 HTTP status code tomcat container JDBC connection to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I have a custom Tomcat container (8080) running a webapp and a MySql container (3306) that the webapp is supposed to connect to using JDBC. Both containers are on the same User-defined bridge network. I confirmed that they have a connection by pinging each other.

Tomcat DataSource JNDI configuration in tomcat/conf/context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbname" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="200" maxIdle="20" maxWait="100000"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1" validationInterval="30000" removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" testWhileIdle="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="120000" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="username" password="password" url="jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/dbname" />
```

Things I've tried:

- putting mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar (JDBC driver) inside tomcat/lib
- installing mysql-connector-j-8.0.31-1.el7.noarch.rpm (Tomcat container OS is Amazon Linux 2)

The frontend is accessible at: http://localhost:8080/app. But when I try to hit the backend, I get a 500 HTTP status error code in developer console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There will be an error log on the Tomcat side.  It is likely in `tomcat/logs/catalina.out`.  Take a look in there to determine the underlying issue.

Comment: I was able to get a connection to the DB using both telnet and netcat. I checked the Catalina logs for errors, and the errors were like:

'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure'

Comment: I connected the Tomcat app to the MySql container from my host machine with the same exact context.xml configuration and it worked perfectly fine.

I think it might be a container issue with Tomcat

Comment: `Communications link failure` sounds like your Docker compose doesn't have the networking correct.  Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74175821/edit) your question and add that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a dependency that the 500 error code was complaining about.